# Comments are out of order

Tags: support, comments

Open up [If Google Drive doesn't count Google documents against storage space, can other formats be embedded or transferred to Google documents?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62697/if-google-drive-doesnt-count-google-documents-against-storage-space-can-other)

Scroll down to the comments on the original post. Below is a screenshot where I have annotated the first three comments as C1, C2, and C3, respectively:

[image: comments_screenshot]

Comment **C1** starts with:

> @pnuts have I tried doing what? ...

Which is clearly to be answering a different comment from @Celeritas.  And comment **C2** does not seem to be the first comment, either. It is difficult to ascertain the proper order at this point.

Many of the comments are out of order. It is quite difficult for me to ascertain the correct order.

This seems to be a defect in the stackexchange system.

Additionally, is there a way to allow someone, with suitable reputation perhaps, to retroactively repair the ordering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very likely that several previous and middle comments were deleted, so while based on the comment content they currently look to be in an incorrect order, comments are always shown on the order that were posted, older first, newer last, in this case and considering the mentioned criteria the order is correct.

So there, is no bug.

Regarding "retroactively repair de ordering" currently that is not possible. To make a feature request as this is about a feature of the whole SE network, please post it on https://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: yep, deleted comments in between

Comment: Ok. I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Note that the seemingly out-of order comments can easily be marked for deletion after copying the essentials into the question body. (Two of them are already gone without the edits)